# Is there a way to convert 2.7x files to 2.4x?

Tags: mesh, blend-files, compatibility

I am doing some meshing for Fallout 3/New Vegas. For a while I would make the mesh in Blender 2.71 and then I would try to open up the same .blend mesh in Blender 2.49b (since that is what  making meshes for Fallout 3/New Vegas limits me to) to add in the collision meshes as well as export it to a NIF file, and make whatever changes I needed to in Nifskope.

When opening the mesh in Blender 2.49b, I get the message depicted below, and when I would hit okay and the file would open. Only the wireframe of the mesh would display rather than the actual mesh that should normally show up that's a shaded object.

I know 2.49b is old but is there something I could do with meshes edited in Blender 2.71 to make them usable in an older version of blender?

[image: 270 Files Message]

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: If it's just mesh data, you can always export to a `.obj` and import that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a lot of new data may not translate well into 2.49 as ideasman42 explains, there is an option if you **only want to transfer mesh** objects.

When you use 'File->Save As' there is a 'Use Legacy Mesh Format' option that will ensure no n-gon data is saved. This allows 2.49 to open a simple mesh with face data intact.

[image]

Comment: Is this feature gone in 2.8 and 2.9?

Comment: @MicroMachine Yes. It *was* going to be removed from 2.79 but they changed to removing it from 2.8+ Details  can be [found here](https://developer.blender.org/T62793)

Answer (score 3):

No, data from newer Blend files which is unsupported in older Blender versions doesn't have a migration path (particles and animation for example).

In some cases you could export to a format that 2.4x can read, this will will only work for some limited cases *(although in theory this can be made to work as long as 2.4x supports the same feature-set)*

In most cases it would be less trouble to update whatever tools you you're missing to support Blender 2.7x.